# What is the difference between off vs. from?

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between off vs. from? For example, I fall from the car or I fall off the car?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I fall **from** the car" means there was no specific relation between you and the car before you fell. 
In this usage it is more likely to refer to you being **in** the car. You could equally have been on top of it, or hanging from it.

"I fall **off** the car" means you were **on** the car before you fell. It is more specific in its usage as it indicates your relation to the car before falling.

Comment: _From_ is just a generalized source. _Off_ refers to orientation with respect to gravity. If it's _on the table_ or _on the car_ it's above and resting upon the top, and if it moves _off_, it moves from that position. _It came from the bottle_ means it was contained in the bottle, but _It came off the bottle_ refers to a lid or other outside piece that detached.